# Is it possible to run arbitrary Java code in the Activity's onCreate method for a Flash project?

Tags: java, android, actionscript-3, air

If I have an Android Java class extending the Activity class. Is it possible to execute those methods from Actionscript 3? And if so could you provide a simple example or link?

Comment: Maybe you could take a look at Native extensions in Adobe AIR. Example : http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/developing-native-extensions-air.html